# How to elegantly flip a BOOL, without a warning?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to simply flip a `BOOL` variable, but this generates a [lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170) warning.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

```
BOOL bCloseButtons = FALSE;
bCloseButtons = !bCloseButtons;                 // Intellisense generate a logical-bitwise mismatch
bCloseButtons = bCloseButtons ? FALSE : TRUE;   // works, but not elegant in my eye
```

```
CButton m_btnPumpP1;
BOOL bLocked = FALSE;
m_btnPump_P1.EnableWindow(!bLocked);           // Intellisense generate a logigal-bitwise mismatch
m_btnPump_P1.EnableWindow(!((bool)bLocked))    // horrible, not readable
```

Comment: what is the warning exactly? Please include it in the question

Comment: create a function called NOT? e.g. `static constexpr BOOL NOT(const BOOL value) { return  (value==TRUE) :  ? FALSE : TRUE); }` then you can use `EnableWindow(NOT(bLocked));`. The constexpr ensures most of the work will be done at compile time. I mean that is what functions are for, making code more readable. The reason for the warning is that BOOL isn't a type, but a macro so BOOL resolves to int. (thanks windows api... not)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `BOOL`/`TRUE`/`FALSE` instead of `bool`/`true`/`false`?

Comment: That's because `BOOL` is an integer type, not a true boolean type (like the C++ `bool` type). It's actually defined as `typedef int BOOL;`

Comment: @SimonKraemer BOOL is what the windows API requires (sadly enough)

Comment: does intellisense also generate the same warning for `int x = 1; x = !x;` ? If yes, then I'd just go with the warning. Warnings are to remind you that something looks fishy. Using `!` on an `int` (thats what `BOOL` actually is) does look fishy, but its just what you want. Warning acknowledged and continue...

Comment: The reason for `BOOL` is that the Windows API is older than the real `bool` type.

Comment: What compiler are you using? If it's Visual Studio, it's not a compiler "warning", it's a linter warning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch that you can configure

Comment: `bCloseButtons = !bCloseButtons;` is correct. If you get a warning then disable that

Comment: Does Intellisense complain if you pass an actual `bool`, instead of `BOOL`?

Comment: @pep *"BOOL is what the windows API requires (sadly enough)"* - Great. What would have been *your* choice? Make sure you understand that you're making that choice in the late 1980's. Also make sure that you'll be guaranteeing ABI stability. Now, what's really, *really* sad is someone comparing a `BOOL` value against `TRUE` for equality. Honestly, one of simplest types there is, and you're getting the semantics wrong.

Comment: @pep That doesn't answer the question. Apparently you're taking offense with the fact, that Microsoft maintains an ABI-stable API, but haven't explained, how you would have done the same without using something like a `BOOL`. Care to elaborate? And no, you don't need a `reinterpret_cast` to *properly* use a `BOOL` value. Just don't ever compare it against `TRUE` for equality (or inequality) and that's it. It is literally **this** simple.

Comment: @MikeVine `!0` is guaranteed to be `1` by the standard

Comment: @M.M you are right. I was conflating this with sign extending a single bit BOOL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `bool` value in your code instead. Flipping a `bool` is a simple matter of applying the unary `!`-operator, e.g. `value = !value;`.

Passing a `bool` value into an API that expects a `BOOL` (aka `int`) value implicitly performs [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) from `bool` to `int`. This is well defined and will not trigger any warnings.

Likewise, if a `BOOL` return value needs to be converted to a value of type `bool`, that conversion is also implicit. The value `0` becomes `false`, and all other values become `true`. This will not raise any warnings either. If code wants to be explicit about this conversion the following expression produces a `bool` value following the implicit conversion rules: `value_abi != FALSE`.

---

A bit of rationale: [`BOOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) is a type alias for a signed 32-bit integer. It exists solely to describe an API in a way that's ABI-stable, so that code compiled today will continue to run a decade from now without having to be recompiled. It is strictly there to establish a binary contract between the caller and the implementation of a function.

It's not generally useful to keep those ABI types in client code. If you are modeling a flag in C++, then clearly a `bool`ean value is the most appropriate type. When it comes time to pass this value into an API you would then convert it to the expected ABI type. In case of a `bool` value this is done automatically as part of the integral type promotion rules of the C++ programming language. At other times you may have to explicitly perform the conversion, though that is extremely rare.